# Can you explain sed 's/$/\r/g'?

Tags: regex, sed

I tried command `sed 's/$/\r/g' linux.txt > linux2win.txt` to convert the text file from Linux to Windows.

And it works!  All `\n` are converted to `\r\n`

For example, `hello, world \n` is converted to `hello, world \r\n`

What confuses me is that what exactly `$` refers to?  `\n`? or an empty char before `\n`? I don't even know what I replaced.

Comment: This might help:  [The Stack Overflow Regular Expressions FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/3776858)

Comment: That command does the opposite of what you're saying.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dollar sign in regular expression and new line character](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13912373/dollar-sign-in-regular-expression-and-new-line-character)

Comment: See [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#BRE-vs-ERE), [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#regexp-extensions) and last paragraph of [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#The-_0022s_0022-Command). The last two references only for GNU sed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answers/comments so far stating that `$` matches the end of line are misleading. `$` in a regexp matches end of string, that is all. The reason it **appears** to match end of line in sed is that by default sed reads 1 line at a time so in that context (but not in others) each string it's operating on does end at the end of the line.

So `$` matches end-of-string and if your string ends at the end of a line then `$` matches at the end of the line but if your string contains multiple lines (e.g. in sed you can create a multi-line string stored in a buffer) then `$` does not match at the end of any given line, it simply and consistently matches at the end of the string.

Similarly `^` matches start-of-string, btw, not start-of-line as you may hear people claim.

wrt your comment:

```
my original line is hello, world \n$ and $ is invisible , and $ is replaced by \r, now my line is hello, world\n\r$ .`
```

No, that is not what is happening. Your original line is:

```
hello, world\n
```

and sed reads one `\n`-separated line at a time so what is read into seds buffer is the string:

```
hello, world
```

Now `$` is a regexp metacharacter that matches the end-of-string so given the above string `$` will match after the `d` (and `^` would match before `h`) so when you do

```
s/$/\r/
```

It changes the above string to:

```
hello world\r
```

and then when sed prints it out it adds back the newline (because a string with no terminating newline is not a text line per POSIX) and to outputs:

```
hello world\r\n
```

Note that `$` is never part of the string, it's just a metacharacter that when used in a regexp matches the end of the string so you can test for characters appearing just at the end of a string or do other operations (like the above) after the end of the string.

Comment: Thanks!   This answer really helps me! I didn't know that sed would consume one `\n`.  Without your answer maybe I will misunderstand `$` in  regexp for a long time.

Answer (score 0):

`$` matches the end of line, so the command:

```
sed 's/$/\r/g'
```

simply adds `\r` to the end of line, which is *not* what you say. If the input is "hello, world \r\n", the output would be "hello, world \r\n".

Comment: @PYL The command simply "appends" `\r` to the end of line (it actually replaces the "last place" with a `\r`).

Comment: I think of it in this way: my original line is hello, world \n$ and $ is invisible , and $ is replaced by \r, now my line is hello, world\n\r$ . It is weird ,isn't it?

Comment: wrt `If the input is "hello, world \r\n", the output would be "hello, world \r\n"` - that depends on the environment you're running in and whether or not the underlying C primitives allow the `\r` from the input to get through to `sed`. If you ran on cygwin with sed in binary mode, for example, then the output would be `"hello, world \r\r\n"`

Answer (score 0):

The premise of your question is flawed.  The `sed` command you present converts Linux-style line terminators (newline alone) to Windows-style (carriage-return / newline), not the other way around.

It works like this:

- the `$` is a regex metacharacter that matches the zero-width end of the line (i.e. just prior to the line terminator, if any).
- the substitution string is a carriage return character (expressed as `\r`); it replaces the zero-width character sequence matched by the regex, in effect inserting the carriage return immediately before the newline

The trailing `g` in the sed command specifies that all matches in each line should be replaced; it is superfluous because the cannot be more than one match per line.

Note also that this can be slightly quirky: if the input file does not end with a newline, then the output will end with just `\r`, because the end of the file is then the end of the last line.

Comment: I think of it in this way: my original line is hello, world \n$ and $ is invisible , and $ is replaced by \r, now my line is hello, world\n\r$ . It is weird ,isn't it?

Comment: No, @PYL, it is not weird at all.  The newlines in the input file are not considered *part of* the lines by `sed`.  They are line terminators -- the line ends just before, and the next line starts just after.  `sed` consumes line terminators on input, and (by default) introduces new ones on output.  You can get newlines into `sed`'s pattern space by other means, but you do not get them from simply reading a line into the pattern space.