# Syntax clarification: What does the $ mean in webpack config?

Tags: javascript, webpack, syntax, babeljs

I am wondering what this particular notation does inside webpack (or other config files).

```
module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: "babel-loader",
                    options: {
                        cacheDirectory: true,
                        cacheCompression: false,
                        envName: "development"
                    }
                }
            },
...
```

Inside rules.test, there is "/.js$/" . What does the $ sign imply?

Comment: That is a regular expression. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13912373/dollar-sign-in-regular-expression-and-new-line-character#13912609

Comment: In regular expressions, $ means "ends with".

Comment: $  matches position just after the last character of the string

Answer (score 0):

The `$` sign here is the regular expression (regex) [end of line anchor](https://howtodoinjava.com/java/regex/start-end-of-string/) and asserts that a pattern only matches if it is found at the end of the line.

In this case, the pattern `/\.js$/` is matching the `.js` file extension at the end of a file path.

Comment: FWIW, if the `m` flag is not specified it matches the end of the string.