# C# regex for conditional operators example eq:2 , ne:3

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I wanted to write an regex in C# for strings which can comprise of any operator and operand value. These operators are string characters like eq for equals , ct = contains & bt for between , eq for equals.

i get strings into backend like eq=4. But during test someone tested my code with garbage values to my API and the string was eq:**+4.

Now i want to build an regex such that it will validate string against regex values like eq:5 or bt:8-9.

JUST A NOTE : exlcuding between operator no other  operator should have such value like eq:4-6.

i have done this @"^\b(eq | ne | gt | lt | ge | le | ct | bt)\w\b : ? (\d | - ) ? \d"

seems im close but need some guidance  to get this properly working.

Any help or suggestion is welcome.

Comment: All spaces are meaningful in the pattern (unless you use `RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace`), are you sure they must be there?

Comment: Great point sir. I dont want white spaces. looks like i need to remove them first and then need to evaluate againts regex string.

Comment: 1) negative values is getting accepted with every operator code
 example ge:-05
 
 Rest its working fantastic. I'm stunned.
 
 2) Between operator is not working example bt:1-10

Comment: Right, forgot about 2). Try `@"^(eq|[gln]e|[bclg]t)\s*:\s*\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?:-\d+(?:\.\d+)?)?\z"`. So, you do not want to support negative values?

Comment: Yes sir. I don't want negatives values in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```cs
@"^(eq|[gln]e|[bclg]t)\s*:\s*\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?:-\d+(?:\.\d+)?)?\z"
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/BT5ou5/1). *Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(eq|[gln]e|[bclg]t)`
- `\s*:\s*` - a colon enclosed with zero or more whitespaces
- `\d+(?:\.\d+)?` - an int/float number (one or more digits and then an optional sequence of a dot and one or more digits)
- `(?:-\d+(?:\.\d+)?)?` - an optional sequence of a `-`, one or more digits and then an optional sequence of a dot and one or more digits
- `\z` - the very end of string.

See the [difference between `$` and `\z` anchors](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13912373/3832970) in .NET regex.

Edit:

It seems only for `bt` ranges are accepted, so you need

```cs
@"^(?:eq|[gln]e|[clg]t|(bt))\s*:\s*\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?(1)(?:-\d+(?:\.\d+)?)?)\z"
```

Comment: wiktor, your earlier regex (^(eq|[gln]e|[bclg]t)\s*:\s*-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?\z) was working good to exclude strings like eq:5-6. For only between it should be like that becuase its a range for e.g. bt:1-5   .But this regex is passing eq:5-6 strings and for other operator codes as well.

Comment: @THINKING I updated the answer.

Comment: I would like to learn from you about mastering regex. You are a master. Please leave here your website or YT channel. And thanks you so much for the help man. Once again appreciate it.

Comment: @THINKINGMACHINE You can see the link to [my "Regex Quickies" YT channel in my profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3832970/wiktor-stribi%c5%bcew?tab=profile).

Answer (score 0):

`(eq|ne|gt|lt|ge|le|ct|bt):-?[0-9]+(--?[0-9]+)?`

or with named group:
`@"(?<operator>eq|ne|gt|lt|ge|le|ct|bt):(?<firstValue>-?[0-9]+)(-(?<secondValue>-?[0-9]+))?$"`

Without negative value:
`@"(?<operator>eq|ne|gt|lt|ge|le|ct|bt):(?<firstValue>[0-9]+)(-(?<secondValue>[0-9]+))?$"`

demo : https://regex101.com/r/HWnIq9/1

Comment: 1) negative values is getting accepted with every operator code
 example ge:-05
 
 Rest its working fantastic